# PostgreSQL - Write a query to make sure this user sees only their own data

Tags: postgresql

I can not find a mistake where it could be all the time i get this messange - Invalid syntax for type integer: "rentaluser". When i change user from postgresql to mine created i have this mistake when trying get with `SELECT`.

```sql
CREATE ROLE rentaluser LOGIN PASSWORD 'rentalpassword';
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE dvd_rental TO rentaluser;

CREATE ROLE rental;
GRANT rental TO rentaluser;

ALTER TABLE rental ENABLE ROW LEVEL SECURITY;
ALTER TABLE payment ENABLE ROW LEVEL SECURITY;

CREATE POLICY rental_policy ON rental TO rentaluser
  USING (customer_id = current_user::integer);

CREATE POLICY payment_policy ON payment TO rentaluser
  USING (customer_id = current_user::integer);

SET ROLE rentaluser;

SELECT * FROM rental;
SELECT * FROM payment;
```

Comment: As to why this could've worked on user `postgres`: by default it has [`superuser` and `bypassrls` attributes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/role-attributes.html). On top of that, unless you [`ALTER TABLE ...` **`FORCE`** `ROW LEVEL SECURITY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html#SQL-ALTERTABLE-DESC-FORCE-ROW-LEVEL-SECURITY), not just `ENABLE`, the table owner also bypasses all policies on it.

Answer (score 0):

As is explained in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html), `current_user` is of type `text`.
In your case, `current_user = 'rentaluser'`, obviously impossible to convert to an integer.

In your queries, you need to replace `current_user::integer` by (parentheses included to make it a scalar subquery):

```sql
(SELECT oid::integer FROM pg_catalog.pg_roles WHERE rolname = current_user)
```

---

On a related note, you may want to use `session_user` instead of `current_user`.

`session_user` remains unaffected by [`SET ROLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-set-role.html).
The only way to change it on an active connection is with the [`SET SESSION AUTHORIZATION`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-set-session-authorization.html) command, which requires the initial session user to be a superuser; it should not be the case for the regular users on your database.

This means you can have your application use `set role` for some purpose while your policy would remain unaffected, thanks to the guarantee users cannot change their own `session_user` (i.e. it stays equal to the login used to connect to the DB).

I leave it up to you to assess the impact of how `session_user` behaves compared to `current_user`